# Take quantity of an order and the price of the objetcs that belongs to, to show the total in Rails 6

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have the object `Tool` with a `price` and a `ToolsOrder` for every sale with a `quantity`. I need to show total of the sales

```
Tool has many: tools_orders
ToolsOrders belongs_to: tool
```

I think in something like this or similar? I can't make it work

```
ToolsOrder.sum("quantity * Tool.price")
```

How can I calculate the total sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it's useful to read error messages that the code gives you. Assuming the error you got was: `missing FROM-clause entry for table "tool"`. This is saying that you're querying for `price` from table `tool`, but there is no such table in the current query.

You're missing a join.

```rb
ToolsOrder.joins(:tool).sum("quantity * tools.price")
```

It can be made safer using Arel though if you'd like.

```rb
ToolsOrder.joins(:tool).sum(ToolsOrder.arel_table[:quantity] * Tool.arel_table[:price])
```

Now there's not pure sql, that is easy to make typos in (Tool vs tools) and is open to sql injections.

Comment: Thanks , a litle problem a have quantity in both tables , one is the stock and the order the sale and now i have this erro
PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR: column reference "quantity" is ambiguous LINE 1:

Comment: You need to add a table name prefix to quantity as well (`tools_orders.quantity`) to specify which quantity you mean. Or use the Arel solution